# Einstein-Hilbert action on lattice

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, lattice-model

I am wondering how the Einstein-Hilbert action is written on lattice in Euclidean spacetime, and if the metric will still be diagonal if it is possible to write Einstein-Hilbert action on lattice.

Comment: Because of the nature of the context, quantum gravity (lattice regularization), I don't think any references of this sort are easy to read. What sort of thing are you looking for? Are you familiar with Regge calculus?

Comment: Why should the metric be "still" diagonal ? The Kerr-metric has a non-diagonal metric in the continous world  and I am quite sure that it will maintain this property on a lattice.

Comment: I know alittle bit of Regge Calculus but i wonder if the action can be written on (Euclidean) lattice as is done for other fields without worrying about anything other than how the action looks like.